# Problema con la re-dimension de una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Buenas, trabajando con la libreria de *numpy* en python, descubri el siguiente problema, cuando asigno una **matriz auxiliar** a la **matriz principal**, esta ultima toma el tamaño de la **matriz auxiliar**, siendo este el *problema*. A continuacion se muestra un ejemplo.

```
import numpy as np

PRINCIPAL = np.zeros(255, 21)  
print("SALIDA_1 = ", len(PRINCIPAL));

AUXILIAR= np.ones(4, 21)  
print("SALIDA_2 = ", len(AUXILIAR));

PRINCIPAL = AUXILIAR.copy()
print("SALIDA_3 = ", len(PRINCIPAL));
```

Donde la salida es la siguiente:

> $ SALIDA_1 = 255
>
> $ SALIDA_2 = 4
>
> $ SALIDA_3 = 4

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo hacer para que la **matriz principal**, no sea redimensionada, y los valores de la **matriz auxiliar** vallan al inicio de la **matriz principal** manteniendo el tamaño original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es el comportamiento esperado, estas reasignado la variable de forma que ahora apunta a un nuevo objeto. El primer array será simplemente eliminado por el GC.

Para hacer lo que quieres puedes simplemente asignar los valores de la segunda matriz a la primera usando indexación. **Si siempre van a tener el mismo número de columnas** puedes hacer:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.zeros((4, 6))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

>>> b = np.ones((2, 6))
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

>>> a[:b.shape[0]]
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Si queremos hacer esto con un array que tiene menos columnas que el primero basta con indicar si queremos que se agregue a la izquierda o a  la derecha (o en cualquier posición):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.zeros((4, 6))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

>>> b = np.ones((2, 6))
>>> b
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

>>> a[:b.shape[0], -b.shape[1]:] = b
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

>>> a = np.zeros((4, 6))
>>> a[:b.shape[0], :b.shape[1]] = b
>>> a
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

---

**Explicación:**

- En NumPy se puede asignar el valor de un elemento de un array mediante indexación, por ejemplo, dado un array de 3x3 podemos hacer:

  ```
  >>> m = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
  >>> m
  array([[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]])
  >>> m[1, 2] = 8
  >>> m
  array([[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 8],
         [1, 1, 1]])
  ```
- Podemos también hacer un rebanado (slicing) de un array o seleccionar parte de el y asignar valores usando el operador `:` :

  ```
  >>> m = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
  >>> m
  array([[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]])
  >>> m[0:2]
  >>> m
  array([[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 8],
         [1, 1, 1]])
  ```

  Con `m[0:2]` seleccionamos desde la fila 0 hasta la fila 1 (2-1). También podemos asignar:

  ```
  >>> m
  array([[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]])
  >>> m[0:2] = [[9, 9, 9], [7, 7, 7]]
  >>> m
  array([[9, 9, 9],
         [7, 7, 7],
         [7, 8, 9]])
  ```
- También podemos seleccionar filas y columnas:

  ```
  >>> m
  array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])
  >>> m[0:2, 1:3]
  array([[2, 3],
         [5, 6]])
  ```

  Con `m[0:2, 1:3]` le indicamos que seleccione desde la fila 0 a la 1 y desde la columna 1 hasta la 2.
- Si dejamos un valor vacío antes o después de `:` indicamos que se seleccione desde el principio o desde el final:

  ```
  >>> m
  array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])
  >>> m[1:]
  array([[4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]])
  ```

  Con `m[1:]` indicamos que seleccione desde la fila 1 hasta el final del array. Con `m[:, 1]` indicamos que seleccione la columna 1 al completo.
- `array.shape` nos da un array con las dimensiones del array. En nuestro caso el primer elemento son el numero de filas y el segundo el de columnas. Es decir `b.shape[0]` nos da el numero de filas y `b.shape[1]` es el número de columnas.
- Recordemos que el indexado con indices negativos está permitido, `array[-2]` selecciona el penúltimo elemento del array.

Cuando hacemos `a[:b.shape[0]] = b` estamos indicando que seleccione las columnas del array a que van desde la primera hasta el número de columna del array b y les asigne los valores del array b.

Comment: Gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda. Pero no entiendo el funcionaminto de la siguiente linea:    (**a[:b.shape[0], -b.shape[1]:] = b**)

Comment: @MarceloS. he editado la pregunta agregando más información y explicaciones. En realidad si ambos arrays tiene el mismo número de columnas siempre basta con `a[:b.shape[0]]`. Mirate la respuesta a ver si me he medio explicado, si algo no queda claro no dudes en comentarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: **Gracias por la informacion**, fue de mucha ayuda :)